# Segmented control and variable issue

Tags: ios, variables, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to send a segmented control variable to another file but I cant get it, I think I'm quiet close, but I need a little help, what's wrong?

```
--<AdSettingsTVC.m>--

@interface AdSettingsTVC () <UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>

// General Settings
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *serverControl;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *server;

@implementation AdSettingsTVC

- (IBAction)getServer:(UISegmentedControl *)sender{
    ANLogDebug(@"%@ setServidor | Server changed to Settings: %ld", CLASS_NAME, (long)sender.selectedSegmentIndex);
    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
        self.server = @"Server 1";
    } else if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
        self.server = @"Server 2";
    } else if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 2){
        self.server = @"Server 3";
    }   
}

--<Another file.m>--

- (void)requestAdWithURL:(NSURL *)URL {

    AdSettingsTVC *settings = [[AdSettingsTVC alloc] init];

        NSString *nameServer = settings.server  --> doesn't connect
        self.URL = URL ? URL : [self adURLWithBaseURLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", nameServer]];

}
```

Thank you very much

PD: Excuse me for my ignorance, I'm a begginer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the `server` property of `AdSettingsTVC` is private because you have defined it in your `.m` file in a category `AdSettingsTVC()`. Therefore, any other file cannot access it.

Try exposing it in your `.h` file as

```
@interface AdSettingsTVC:UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *server;
```

Also, notice the `strong` property

Comment: Doesn't work :/, it's another file, self is not used to call local variables? Thanks

Comment: sorry, I realized that. I have made changes to my answer accordingly.

Comment: Great :) now I can access by settings.server but is null, any idea of what I'm missing?

Comment: You're doing an alloc/init, but seems that you're creating a new object, right? Where is the first AdSettingTCV created, the one you clicked on the UISegmentedControl?

Comment: I 've use alloc because I though it's the only way to call an interface without using @implementation, should I remove/change it?

Comment: Once you do alloc/init, the object and all it's properties are `init`ialized to `nil`. This is a perfect example where MVC pattern is not used. You need a model to store the `server` value and access that across different `view controllers`

Comment: I'm working as a junior, so I'm modifying a program.. It results that there is an Model called AdSettings.h .m and looking information i quietly understand the idea of MVC. Now my question is what I have to declare in the model. I think the _if_ should stay in the View. Or simply repeat the @property? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you want your server variable to be accessed publicly (accessed by other objects), you must declare the property in the .h file.

So in this case you should move

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *server;
```

into AdSettingsTVC.h.